# How to make array list on image view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

How to make array list on image or something in this program, you can see this picture to make it clear.

[image]

When I click one of the picture, there's no problem, it increments the right text box, but when I swipe, and swipe back, all textboxes become like that, auto filled. I know this code make it happens:

```
qtytext.text = Activitymenu.quantity
```

but how can I make it become array list on picture, so the value will increase with his address?

This is my code:

```
struct Activitymenu
{
    static var dataact:Array<AnyObject> = Array <AnyObject>()
    static var quantity: String = ""
}
class CustomCellActivity: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var leftlabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightlabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var qtytext: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var decrease: UIImageView!
    var dataFilePath: String?
    var value = 0
    var checks:Bool = false
    var dx = 0


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.decrease.userInteractionEnabled = true
        qtytext.text = Activitymenu.quantity
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        qtytext.resignFirstResponder()
        self.endEditing(true)

    }
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        let touch: UITouch? = touches.first as? UITouch
        if(touch?.view == myImageView)
        {
            value += 30
            qtytext.text = String(value)

        }
        if(touch?.view == decrease)
        {
            if(value >= 30)
            {
                value -= 30;
                qtytext.text = String(value)

            }

        }
        qtytext.resignFirstResponder()//respon pada editing textbox
        self.endEditing(true)
        var data = Activitiesdata(type: leftlabel.text!, amount: qtytext.text.toInt()!)
        var temp:Activitiesdata
        temp = data
        var idx = 0
        if(temp.amount-30 > 0) {
            temp.amount -= 30

        }
        data = Activitiesdata(type: leftlabel.text!, amount: qtytext.text.toInt()!)
        var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(data)
        var tempJson = JSONSerializer.toJson(temp)

        for(var i = 0; i < Activitymenu.dataact.count; i++){
            if(Activitymenu.dataact[i] as! String == tempJson){
                self.checks = true
                self.dx = i
            }
        }
        if(!self.checks) {
            Activitymenu.dataact.append(json)
        }
        else{
            Activitymenu.dataact[self.dx] = json
        }
        Activitymenu.quantity = String(value)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Activitymenu.dataact, forKey: "Aktivitas")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
       println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Aktivitas"))


    }

    func setCell(leftlabeltext: String, rightlabeltext: String, imagename: String)
    {
        self.leftlabel.text = leftlabeltext
        self.rightlabel.text = rightlabeltext
        self.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: imagename)

    }

}
```

in the other words to say, I want they keep the value when I swipe and swipe back..I'm using JSON on my controller to fetch the table data

```
import UIKit

struct JSONActivity
{
    static var jsondata = ""
    static var qty = 0
}


class TableControllerActivities: UITableViewController {

    var items = NSMutableArray()
    var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
    var json:String = ""
    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
    var arrayOfMenu: [Activity] = [Activity]()

    @IBAction func setting(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SettingView", sender: self)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let stringKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//        println("tes")
        println(stringKey.objectForKey("Aktivitas"))
        self.setUpMenu()
        self.myTableView.delegate = self
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
//        var stringData: String? = JSONData as? String
//        var json: String = JSONData.parseJSONString

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOfMenu.count //hitung banyak data pada array
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //fungsi agar json dapat membaca tiap row pada storyboard
        var shortDate: String {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        }

        let cell: CustomCellActivity = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCellActivity
        let menu = arrayOfMenu[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCell(menu.type, rightlabeltext: menu.unit, imagename: menu.image)
        //memasukkan data ke json, misal textbox isi 3 maka akan diwrite ke json 3
        var data = Activitiesdata(type: menu.type, amount: String(cell.value).toInt()!)
        var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(data)
        JSONActivity.jsondata = json
        JSONActivity.qty = String(cell.value).toInt()!
//        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("Aktivitas")
//        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
//
//      println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Aktivitas"))
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func do_table_refresh()//mengapdet / merefresh data
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func setUpMenu() //membaca json pada setiap arraynya
    {
        var json: JSON = JSON (data: NSData())
        DataManager.getactivityDataFromFileWithSuccess{ (data) -> Void in
            json = JSON(data: data)
            let results = json["results"]
            for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < json["Activity"].count; i++) {
                if let type = json["Activity"][i]["type"].string {
                    //println("Tipe : \(type)")
                    if let icon: AnyObject = json["Activity"][i]["icon"].string {
                        self.items.addObject(icon)
                        if let unit_id = json["Activity"][i]["unit_id"].string {
                            //println("Logo : \(unit_id)")
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.tableView!.reloadData()})
                                var menu = Activity(type: type, unit: unit_id, image: icon as! String)
                                    self.arrayOfMenu.append(menu)
                                    self.TableData.append(type + unit_id )
                                    self.do_table_refresh()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also using `NSUserdefaults`, but it seems doesn't work at all, it print all the text box...

```
let myquantity = Activitymenu.quantity
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myquantity, forKey: "SavedStringKey")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        let stringKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        qtytext.text = stringKey.stringForKey("SavedStringKey")
```

Comment: Could you please post your Datasource implementation. I am not sure how your code works, but it seems all the logic happens in custom cell implementation which can result, due to Reuse, to duplication the values.

Wouldn't it be better to store the values in Dictionary or anything else and not in struct associated with just one cell? 

Furthermore where do you set initial value for the Label with amount ? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: i've tried dictionary, but it always make errors, i already posted my controller, is that what you want? mmm.. i assign the value on the custom cell, and the increment function there, and then i apply it to qty text.. i still don't understand about swift because i still at internship and I'm a newbie here :( @RadimHalfar

Comment: Why the hell did you cancel my edits? It made your post readable and fixed errors. Don't do this.

Comment: errr @EricD. i didn't do anything.. sorry, can u try again

Comment: Ok, sorry for being sensible about this... Maybe you did an edit while I was doing mine and it conflicted. I'm doing the edit again, don't worry.

Comment: okay thank you @EricD. yes, I've edited my post a moment ago..

Comment: Basically you store your data only locally to structs.

Comment: do u have a conclusion about this problem, i also using nsdefaults , i edited a moment ago..but still the same @RadimHalfar

Comment: Apparently you are using same key for every value. So no wonder you get same values all the time. Just change the key  "SavedStringKey" to "SavedStringKey1"for first value, "SavedStringKey2" etc.